# Highlight td that contains searched text from input

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' id='search'>
<table class='searchtbl'>
   <tr><th>ID</th><th>DESCRIPTION</th></tr>
   <tr><td>1</td><td><input type='text' value='FROG'></td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td><td><input type='text' value='MOUSE'></td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td><td><input type='text' value='CAT'></td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlighted {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I'm trying to highlight the `<td>` that contains the search term, wether it is in the td or in the input, from `#search` by adding `.highlighted` class to it:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var data = this.value.toUpperCase().split(" ");    
    $(".searchtbl").find("tr").not("tr:first").find("td").each(function (index, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            // Highlight
            if ($elem.text().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) != -1) {
                $elem.addClass('highlighted');   
            } else {
                $elem.removeClass('highlighted');   
            }
        }
    })     
})
```

For some reason it is not highlighting the cell.

https://jsfiddle.net/fabriziomazzoni79/zpaLv4pm/

Comment: Outside of the exact problem you're facing, there's a minor improvement you could make.  Firstly wrap your header row with `<thead>` and the other rows with `<tbody>` then you can do `$(.searchtbl).find("tbody tr")` without needing `.not("tr:first")`

Comment: Also, your code is slightly flawed if you're trying to highlight multiple items. You're adding and removing the class based on each individual item in your `data` array.  That means that if you add the class because you've found the first word in the array, you will remove it straight away if you **don't** find it in the second word in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the text is not directly inside the `td` element, but inside the input inside the element. So just replace:

```
if ($elem.text().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) != -1) {
```

with

```
if ($elem.find('input').length > 0 && 
    $elem.find('input').val().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) != -1) {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zpaLv4pm/6/

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var data = $(this).val().toUpperCase().split(" ");
    $(".searchtbl input[type='text']").each(function (i, e) {
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            // Highlight
            if ($(this).val().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) != -1) {
                $(this).closest("td").addClass('highlighted');
            } else {
                $(this).closest("td").removeClass('highlighted');
            }
        }
    })     
})
```

Answer (score 2):

See this is the working code i have added.
Your problem was you are only searching text in **td**.

But in inside **td** you have **input** tag which were you forgot to search.
You need to search it tooo.

so i have correct this please have a look this will work.

May be this will help

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#search").keyup(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(".searchtbl").find("tr").not("tr:first").find("td").removeClass('highlighted');
      $(".searchtbl").find("tr").not("tr:first").find("td").find(".inputType").removeClass('highlighted');
      return false;
    }
    var data = this.value.toUpperCase().split(" ");
    $(".searchtbl").find("tr").not("tr:first").find("td").each(function(index, elem) {
      var $elem = $(elem);
      for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        // Highlight
        if ($elem.text().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) != -1) {
          $elem.addClass('highlighted');
        } else {
          $elem.removeClass('highlighted');
        }
        //console.log();

        if ($elem.find(".inputType").length == 1) {

          if ($elem.find(".inputType").val().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d]) != -1) {
            $elem.addClass('highlighted');
            $elem.find(".inputType").addClass('highlighted');
          } else {
            $elem.removeClass('highlighted');
            $elem.find(".inputType").removeClass('highlighted');
          }
        }

      }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='search'>
<table class='searchtbl'>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' value='FROG' class="inputType">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' value='MOUSE' class="inputType">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' value='CAT' class="inputType">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:
search for "input" instead of "td"
and use "val()" instead of "text()"

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var data = this.value.toUpperCase().split(" ");    
    $(".searchtbl").find( ":input" ).each(function (index, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                //alert($elem.val());
            // Highlight
            if ($elem.val().toUpperCase().indexOf(data[d].toUpperCase()) != -1) {
                $elem.addClass('highlighted');

            } else {
                $elem.removeClass('highlighted');   
            }
        }
    })     
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nc2k21gt/